# How to split an array to minimize the absolute value of the subtraction of the sum of the two arrays?

Tags: c#

Given an array of type double (the elements can be repeated),
split the array into two arrays, `arrA` and `arrB`,
Make the absolute value diff of the subtraction of the sum of `arrA` and the sum of `arrB` the smallest, and return the two arrays of a and b, and the smallest absolute value diff.
The following are possible solutions, but not all cases are covered. How should I optimize it?

```
    static double Divide_A_B(List<double> args, out List<double> a, out List<double> b)
    {
        var array = args;
        int middleIndex = array.Count / 2;
        if (array.Count == 1)
        {
            a = array;
            b = new List<double>();
            return Math.Abs(array[0]);
        }
        else if (array.Count == 2)
        {
            a = new List<double>() { array[0] };
            b = new List<double>() { array[1] };
            return Math.Abs(array[0] - array[1]);
        }
        var (leftArray, rightArray) = (new List<double>(), new List<double>());
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i <= middleIndex)
            {
                leftArray.Add(array[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                rightArray.Add(array[i]);
            }
        }
        double diff = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            (double leftSum, double rightSum) = (leftArray.Sum(), rightArray.Sum());

            if (leftSum < rightSum)
            {
                var tempArray = leftArray;
                leftArray = rightArray;
                rightArray = tempArray;
                var tempSum = leftSum;
                leftSum = rightSum;
                rightSum = tempSum;
            }
            diff = leftSum - rightSum;
            int flag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < leftArray.Count; i++)
            {
                if (leftArray[i] > 0)
                {
                    if (leftArray[i] <= diff / 2 || leftArray[i] < diff)
                    {
                        rightArray.Add(leftArray[i]);
                        double num = leftArray[i];
                        leftArray.Remove(leftArray[i]);
                        flag++;
                        leftSum -= num;
                        rightSum += num;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < rightArray.Count; j++)
                {
                    double diffAfterSwap = Math.Abs((leftSum - leftArray[i] + rightArray[j]) - (rightSum - rightArray[j] + leftArray[i]))
                    if (diffAfterSwap < diff)
                    {
                        var (targetLeftNum, targetRightNum) = (leftArray[i], rightArray[j]);
                        leftArray.Remove(targetLeftNum);
                        leftArray.Add(targetRightNum);
                        rightArray.Remove(targetRightNum);
                        rightArray.Add(targetLeftNum);
                        flag++;
                        diff = diffAfterSwap;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rightArray.Count; i++)
            {
                if (rightArray[i] < 0)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(rightArray[i]) <= diff / 2 || Math.Abs(rightArray[i]) < diff)
                    {
                        leftArray.Add(rightArray[i]);
                        double num = rightArray[i];
                        rightArray.Remove(rightArray[i]);
                        rightSum -= num;
                        leftSum += num;
                        flag++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < leftArray.Count; j++)
                {
                    double diffAfterSwap = Math.Abs(rightSum - leftSum - 2 * rightArray[i] + 2 * leftArray[j]);
                    if (diffAfterSwap < diff)
                    {
                        var (targetLeftNum, targetRightNum) = (leftArray[j], rightArray[i]);
                        rightArray.Remove(targetRightNum);
                        rightArray.Add(targetLeftNum);
                        leftArray.Remove(targetLeftNum);
                        leftArray.Add(targetRightNum);
                        flag++;
                        diff = diffAfterSwap;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        a = leftArray;
        b = rightArray;
        return diff;
    }
```

There is a wrong test case, The final diff should be 0 but the algorithm returned 194:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<double> li = new List<double>() { 310, 226, 231, 218, 291, 267, 321, 332, 352, 344 };
    List<double> a,b = new List<double>();
    double diff = Divide_A_B(li, out a, out b);
    Console.WriteLine("A:");
    foreach (var item in a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("B:");
    foreach (var item in b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"diff: { diff}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You're not using arrays but lists.

Comment: Consider narrowing more the problem, incidentaly, you should be able to debug it step by step and find out the exact problem.

Comment: Do you really need to solve for `double` or are the arguments integers in disguise? This matters because adding and subtracting `double`s can yield wildly different results depending on what elements are considered; in particular, if a very small number is added to a very large number, the smaller one may effectively end up as zero. This means both that the order of numbers is actually relevant (not just which numbers end up in which half), and the outcome may be "wrong" depending on why you're doing the split.

Comment: Incidentally, this problem is the optimization version of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) with two subsets. It is not trivial, especially if you want the optimal solution. The linked article discusses some approaches.

Comment: @JeroenMostert,  Double is not necessary, I thought about your reply, it may indeed bring wrong results. The problem I want to deal with is enough to use int.

Comment: @Cleptus, I consider using recursion to find the optimal solution. Thank you for your patience.